# Add fruit to basket in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to implement a function which could add the fruit in the basket if the fruit is on the list after the input and pressing "add".
I have done it by using JavaScript, but now I am required to use jQuery library, and I got stucked, it is not working after I entered the text and pressed the add button.
Can anybody help?

This is my HTML file

```html
<h1> Fruit shelf</h1>

<ol id="fruits"></ol>Pick a fruit:
<input type="text" id="newfruit">
<p>Your choice is: <b id='boldStuff2'></b>

<h1>Basket</h1>

<ol id="basket"></ol>
<button>add fruit</button>
```

Below is the JavaScript

```js
var li = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
$("button").click(function () {
    var list = $('#basket');
    var newfruit = $('#newfruit').val();
    $('#boldStuff2').html(newfruit);
    var entry = $('<li></li>');
    var len = li.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (li[i] == newfruit) {
            $("entry").append(document.createTextNode(newfruit));
            $("list").append(entry);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it gives an error, `i` is not defined?

Comment: "*I have done it by using Javascript, but now I am required to use JQuery library*". Why? jQuery IS JavaScript.

Comment: @Oriol I don't think that should be a question, jQuery is a JS library, but it gives a lot of ready-made things also.

Comment: if you want to check if your fruit is on list you should use indexOf() , your script doesnt make sense at all !!

Comment: Could you post your original, working, Javascript solution?  The jquery code seems to be missing something between `var len...` and `if(li[i] == ...`, and i being undefined is a symptom of that.

Comment: @ProllyGeek sorry I didn't post the for loop before, now I just added it.

Comment: I thinks that's working http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/103/, what do you expect from this.

Comment: @kwokkaki what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Mritunjay if you could copy and paste this code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5jLbk0uq/2/) to your Dreamveaver, it works,but not on jsfiddle

Comment: @ProllyGeek please copy and paste the code from here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5jLbk0uq/3/) to your dreamveaver and you can run it, cuz it dosen't work on jsfiddle, i don't know why, that's the result I want to get, when you type the fruit on the list ,it will add the fruits under the basket list.

Comment: @kwokkaki - I don't think everyone here will have a copy of Dreamweaver here.

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 thanks for replaying but problem solved, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do this.

> 

```
var li = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
$("button").click(function () {
    var list = $('#basket');
    var newfruit = $('#newfruit').val();
    $('#boldStuff2').html(newfruit);
    var entry = $('<li></li>');
    var len = li.length;
    /*
    if (li[i] == newfruit) {
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newfruit));
        list.appendChild(entry);
        delete li[i]
    }
    */
    $.each(li, function(i, item){
        if(item == newfruit){
            entry.append((newfruit));
            list.append(entry);
            delete li[i];
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wow! Thank you! It works, well I am just a new guy in html and js, need a lot more work, Thanks again!

Comment: better to use `splice()` for arrays not delete, won't leave behind undefined element at that index and will shorten array length

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is you are declaring 2 jQuery objects `entry` and `list` but when you try to use them again you are wrapping them in quotes which makes them invalid as selectors.

`$('entry')` implies a tagName selector which doesn't exist.

Here's a slightly abbereviated version using `$.inArray()` to look up the value in your array:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var list = $('#basket');
    var newfruit = $('#newfruit').val();
    var isValidFruit = $.inArray(newfruit, li) > -1;
    if (isValidFruit) {
        $('#boldStuff2').html(newfruit);
        var entry = $('<li></li>').text(newfruit);
        list.append(entry);
    }else{
      alert('Not valid');  
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w1ykbr6n/)**</kbd>

Comment: It make lots of sense! Thanks!

Comment: once they are jQuery objects you don't have to wrap them in `$()` again

Answer (score 0):

Just did the quick edit for you
Take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/oon7y8qo/1/

```
var li = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
$("#btnClick").click(function () {
    var list = $('#basket');
    var newfruit = $('#newfruit').val();
    $('#boldStuff2').text(newfruit);
    $.each(li,function(index,value){
        if(value == newfruit)
        {
            list.append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
        }
    })
});
```